# How to create a CoreData Entity with one-to-many relationship with itself (the same Entity)

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, relationship

I am creating a document based app, and currently I am converting my entire project to work with CoreData. The issue that I have right now is that adding a sub folder to an already existing, parent folder (it's just a folder that is not the child of any other folder), causes some issues. when I append/add a new folder to a parent folder, it works perfectly fine. However, when I add/append a folder to another folder (one that isn't a parent folder), then my app will crash/stop responding. I read online that apparently when you call the CoreData default/implemented function for a to-many relationship, it's the same thing as setting the origin of the inverse.

For example, consider this typical to-many relationship:

[image]

```
owner.addToDogs(dog)
```

is the same as

```
dog.person = owner
```

I believe that this is the cause of my issue, because I want to achieve this without calling/setting the inverse (2nd line):

```
folder.addToSubFolders(subFolder)
```

These are my CoreData Relationships (The folder relationship is many-to-many, but it points to the same Entity):
[image]
This is my Folder Class:

```
public class Folder: Item {
    
    public static var parentFolders: [Folder] {
        Folder.getFolders(with: NSPredicate(format: "storedIsParentFolder == true"))
    }
    public static var allFolders: [Folder] {
        Folder.getFolders()
    }
    
    public var documents: Set<Document> { get {(self.storedDocuments as? Set<Document>) ?? Set<Document>()} set {self.storedDocuments = newValue as NSSet}}
    public var subFolders: [Folder]? {
        get {
            if let subs = self.storedSubFolders?.allObjects as? [Folder] {
                return subs.isEmpty ? nil : subs
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set { self.storedSubFolders = NSSet(array: newValue ?? []) }
    }
    
    public var isParentFolder: Bool { get {self.storedIsParentFolder} set {self.storedIsParentFolder = newValue}}
    
    public static func getFolders(with predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [Folder] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Folder> = Folder.fetchRequest()
        if predicate != nil { request.predicate = predicate }
        if let results = try? Item.context.fetch(request) { return results } else { return [] }
        
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(context: Item.context)
        self.title = "New Folder"
    }
    
    convenience init(title: String, isParentFolder: Bool, documents: Set<Document>, subFolders: [Folder]?) {
        self.init(context: Item.context)
        self.title = title
        self.isParentFolder = isParentFolder
        self.documents = documents
        self.subFolders = subFolders
    }
    
    func getParent() -> Folder? {
        return Folder.allFolders.first(where: {$0.subFolders?.contains(self) ?? false})
    }
    
    public override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return Folder(title: self.title, isParentFolder: self.isParentFolder, documents: self.documents, subFolders: self.subFolders)
    }
    
    override func move(to folder: Folder) {
        if folder.subFolders == nil { folder.subFolders = [] }
        let copy = self.copy() as! Folder
        folder.addToStoredSubFolders(copy)
        self.delete()
    }
    
    func hasAncestor(_ ancestor: Folder) -> Bool {
        guard let parent = self.getParent() else { return false }
        if parent == ancestor {
            return true
        } else {
            return parent.hasAncestor(ancestor)
        }
    }
    
    func moveToParentFolders() {
        let copy = self.copy() as! Folder
        copy.isParentFolder = false
        self.delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like your sub folder relationship has itself as the reverse but you still need two relationships even if it is only one entity. So you need a `parentFolder` relationship that is set to the inverse of the `storedSubFolders` relationship

Comment: So are you suggesting that I create a new entity named parentfolder at make that have a relationship to folder? Is there no other way to fix this issue? I’d prefer to use a bool value(isParentFolder) bc there will literally be no difference between parentfolder and folder

Comment: No, you add a new relationship to your existing entity.

Comment: Alright, I added the relationship. Works like a charm! Thanks for your help!